# How to access a parent method from a child class in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, class, oop

What is the right syntax to access a parent method from a child class in Ruby?

```rb
class Parent
    def initialize()
    end
    def p_do_something_1()
    end
    def p_do_something_2()
    end
    class Child
        def initialize()
        end
        def c_do_something_1()
        end
        p_do_something_1 = Parent.p_do_something_1() # What's the right way to do this?
    end
end
```

Comment: `p_do_something_1` is an _instance method_, so you need an instance (`Parent.new`) to call it on. If you want to call it as `Parent.p_do_something_1` you have to make it a _class method_. Also, what is the `p_do_something_1 = ...` assignment supposed to achieve inside the class body of `Child`? The variable is never used afterwards. Can you explain what you are trying to do here?

Comment: Also note that `Child` is merely [nested](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/doc/syntax/modules_and_classes_rdoc.html#label-Nesting) within the `Parent` namespace. For actual [inheritance](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/doc/syntax/modules_and_classes_rdoc.html#label-Inheritance), you have to make `Child` a subclass of `Parent` via `class Child < Parent`. (but then probably without the nesting)

Answer (score 0):

Or use modules:

```rb
module Parent

    def something
        something
    end
end

class Child

    inlude Parent

end

abc = Child.new
abc.something
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, `Child` is not actually inheriting from `Parent` because Ruby has a different syntax for inheritance. Once that is fixed you can call a method on the parent with the same name from the child with `super`.

```
class Parent
  def initialize()
  end

  def method()
    puts "from Parent"
  end
end

class Child < Parent # This means Child inherits from Parent
  def initialize()
  end
  
  def method  
    puts "from Child"
    super # calling the same method from Parent
  end
end

child = Child.new
child.method
#=> from Child
#=> from Parent
```